# How to solve strange behavior in the selector?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a status selector to approve, reject or remove ads. When you select withdraw or reject, a text input opens to add the reason why the ad is rejected or withdrawn. I am using formik to validate the form, but the selector has a strange behavior, when you press one of the options sometimes the default option to select is marked, that is to say, I give the option to withdraw, the input opens to put the reason, but in the selector appears the option to select instead of withdraw, and I have to mark again the desired option so that it is seen well. Could someone help me to solve this behavior?

```
 let selectValue;
        const selectField = ({ form, field, ...props }) => {
           
            return(
        
            <select
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                name={field.name}
                data-accordion={props['data-accordion']}
                onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
                    selectValue = e.currentTarget.value;
                    form.setFieldValue(field.name, selectValue)  
                    setVisibleReasonMessage(selectValue == "3" || selectValue == "4")
                   
                }
                
                }  
                >
                    <option value={""}>Seleccionar</option>
                    {initialValues.status?.toString() !== "2" ?
                    <option value={"2"}>Aprobar</option>
                    :null}
                    {initialValues.status?.toString() !== "2" && initialValues.status?.toString() !== "4" && initialValues.status?.toString() !== "3"? 
                    <option value={"3"}>Rechazar</option>
                    :null
                    }
                    {initialValues.status?.toString() !== "4" ?
                    <option value={"4"}>Retirar</option>
                    :null}
                </select>
        
                )
            } 
 <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
  <Field component={selectField} name="status"  id="" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 block w-full p-2.5">
  </Field> 
  <ErrorMessage name="status" component="span" className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600"/>
  <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">Completa este campo</p>
    </div>  
   </div>
```